# How to disable the onselect event when clicking a list web part on a page?

Tags: web-part

I have a list added to a web part page. When clicking inside the web part (not on a link in the list but in the area around it), the List Tools button (at the top in the ribbon) is selected. Is there a way of disabling this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only reasonable way to do this is to create a custom web part to display your data. For a small number of web parts this would not be an unreasonable solution.

If you had wanted to disable it for all web parts, i think you would have to change some core functionality of SharePoint, which would be incredibly complicated and open the door for strange errors and behavior you might not otherwise see.